# Unable to plot list tuple in Python using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a tuple of polygons(voronoipolys) in a list that is returned by the code below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pytess
points = [(1,1), (5,5), (3,5), (8,1)]
voronoipolys = pytess.voronoi(points)

plt.plot(voronoipolys)
plt.show()
```

I am getting the following error message:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So an easy solve is to use `scipy` instead of `pytess`.

You could do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d

points = [(1,1), (5,5), (3,5), (8,1)]
vor = Voronoi(points)
voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
plt.show()
```

This will produce the following plot:

[image]

The reason you fail to just use `plot` Is because `pytess.voronoi` returns a tuple of either point or None and a polygon so you need to construct the plot yourself.